# Static Methods and Return Values?

Tags: static

Do Static Methods In Salesforce Return Values

Like

`public static integer MethodName(){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do Static Methods In Salesforce Return Values

Yes, they do.

Static methods are as good as any other method except that you don’t invoke those using the instance of the class but rather the class name itself.

You can find more on static methods on [its documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm)

Comment: Thanks Jayant. Please advise if static method and static block, either can initialize the value of static variable.

Comment: Yes and No. Yes - Static blocks are best suited for that. No - because if you use methods to initialize a variable, you will need to ensure that the method is the first one to be called prior of any other method which may be using the same variable.

Comment: Jayant, can you please explain me the outcome of the following code

Public Class Test {
 
   public static integer A;

static {
    A=1000;
}

static{
   A=3000;
}

public static void m1(){
    A=9000;
    }
}

When I execute the following block of code .... I am getting value of A as 3000.

Comment: If you have any other question please open that as a new question. At SFSE we tend to keep question specific to one problem.